# jquery next/previous button for lightbox

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-selectors, image-gallery

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make a lightbox web gallery with jquery.
It's a basic gallery, when you click on an image (thumbnail) in the list, jquery shows the hidden lightbox div, which makes the background dark and brings up the current image (full size) with a white border, with the next/prev and close buttons on the border.
My next/prev buttons work only once, and I don't know how to fix it.
(I haven't done anything with the prev button, so that obviously doesn't work at all.)
Any ideas? Here's the code:

html

```
<ul class="gallery">
        <li> <a href="img/gallery/fullsize/full_foto001.jpg" class="lightbox_trigger"> <img src="img/gallery/thumbnail/thumbnail_foto001.jpg"> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/gallery/fullsize/full_foto002.jpg" class="lightbox_trigger"> <img src="img/gallery/thumbnail/thumbnail_foto002.jpg"> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/gallery/fullsize/full_foto003.jpg" class="lightbox_trigger"> <img src="img/gallery/thumbnail/thumbnail_foto003.jpg"> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/gallery/fullsize/full_foto004.jpg" class="lightbox_trigger"> <img src="img/gallery/thumbnail/thumbnail_foto004.jpg"> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/gallery/fullsize/full_foto005.jpg" class="lightbox_trigger"> <img src="img/gallery/thumbnail/thumbnail_foto005.jpg"> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/gallery/fullsize/full_foto006.jpg" class="lightbox_trigger"> <img src="img/gallery/thumbnail/thumbnail_foto006.jpg"> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/gallery/fullsize/full_foto007.jpg" class="lightbox_trigger"> <img src="img/gallery/thumbnail/thumbnail_foto007.jpg"> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/gallery/fullsize/full_foto008.jpg" class="lightbox_trigger"> <img src="img/gallery/thumbnail/thumbnail_foto008.jpg"> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/gallery/fullsize/full_foto009.jpg" class="lightbox_trigger"> <img src="img/gallery/thumbnail/thumbnail_foto009.jpg"> </a> </li>
    </ul>

<div id="lightbox">

<div id="gallery_content">

</div>
```

jquery

```
 $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
    //prevent default action (hyperlink)
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#lightbox').show('slow');

    var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

    var image_href2 = $(this).parent().next('li').children('a').attr("href");


   $('#gallery_content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />' + 
   '<div id="gallery_close"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/close.png"/> </div>' + 
   '<div id="gallery_next"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/next.png"/> </div>'+
   '<div id="gallery_prev"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/previous.png"/> </div>');

   //next
   $(document).on('click', '#gallery_next', function(){
        $('#gallery_content').html('<img src="' + image_href2 + '" />' +
        '<div id="gallery_close"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/close.png"/> </div>' + 
        '<div id="gallery_next"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/next.png"/> </div>'+
        '<div id="gallery_prev"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/previous.png"/> </div>');

   });


   //previous
   $('#gallery_prev').click(function(){

   });
});
```

Comment: you should try to set your functions out the `lightbox_trigger.click`

Comment: If I do that it doesn't work at all. Not even once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I don't know how "elegant" it is, but it works.
Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
        //prevent default action (hyperlink)
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#lightbox').show('slow');

        $(this).attr('class','this');

        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

        var image_href2 = $('.this').parent().next('li').children('a').attr("href");


       $('#gallery_content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />' + 
       '<div id="gallery_close"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/close.png"/> </div>' + 
       '<div id="gallery_next"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/next.png"/> </div>'+
       '<div id="gallery_prev"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/previous.png"/> </div>');



 });



  //next
  $(document).on('click', '#gallery_next', function(){
            var image_href2 = $('.this').parent().next('li').children('a').attr("href");
            $('#gallery_content').html('<img src="' + image_href2 + '" />' +
            '<div id="gallery_close"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/close.png"/> </div>' + 
            '<div id="gallery_next"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/next.png"/> </div>'+
            '<div id="gallery_prev"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/previous.png"/> </div>');

            $('.this').attr('class', 'remove');
            $('.this').removeAttr('class', 'this');
            $('.remove').parent().next('li').children('a').attr('class', 'this');
            $('.remove').removeAttr('class', 'remove');

  });


  //previous


 //hide 
 $(document).on("click", "#gallery_close", function(event){
        $('.lightbox_trigger').removeAttr('class', 'this');
        $('.lightbox_trigger').removeAttr('class', 'remove');

        $('#lightbox').hide();

 });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say something like

```
$('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
    //prevent default action (hyperlink)
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#lightbox').show('slow');

    var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

    var image_href2 = $(this).parent().next('li').children('a').attr("href");


   $('#gallery_content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />' + 
   '<div id="gallery_close"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/close.png"/> </div>' + 
   '<div id="gallery_next"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/next.png"/> </div>'+
   '<div id="gallery_prev"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/previous.png"/> </div>');
});
//next
    $('#gallery_next').live('click', function(){
         $('#gallery_content').html('<img src="' + image_href2 + '" />' +
         '<div id="gallery_close"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/close.png"/> </div>' + 
         '<div id="gallery_next"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/next.png"/> </div>'+
         '<div id="gallery_prev"> <img src="img/gallery/lightbox/previous.png"/> </div>');
    });
// prev
    $('#gallery_prev').live('click', function() { ... });
```

Comment: "live()" is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, therefore @levi uses "on()".

Comment: That doesn't work. I know what the problem is though. The 'this' selector refers to the thumbnai that you clicked. So if you add 'next' to it, it will select the next one. But this only works one, because next of the clicked thumbnail is the one immedately next to it. So it doesn't work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked javascript error console? If the error is triggered, the script stops executing, that's a common reason why something fires off only once. Besides, I would only replace the image's src, without whole html inside that div.

Comment: How would you change the src? I figured out what the problem is though. The 'this' selector refers to the thumbnai that you clicked. So if you add 'next' to it, it will select the next one. But this only works once, because next of the clicked thumbnail is the one immedately next to it. So it doesn't work after that.

Comment: To change only src, you need to use this: $('#gallery_content').find('img').attr('src', image_href2);